# d3 zoom in on svg on click, zoom out on next double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am zooming in on an svg element using d3.

Currently, the way it is setup you can scroll out and be further away from the image. I only want it to be possible to zoom in on the image. I have tried to set it up so that on double click it zooms in once, and if you double click again it will zoom out, so there should only be two states.

To prevent mousehweel I have tried :

`svg.call(zoom).on("mousewheel.zoom", null);`

I have searched many blogs and tutorials but cannot find anything answering this question.

see code below:

```js
d3.xml("https://boxy-svg.com/images/logos/boxy-svg.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
       svg.selectAll("*").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
   }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want to limit the zoom out or do you want to implement the zoom on click? You've got two different things here.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado hey man! i want to limit the zoom out to nothing more than the original size of the svg as it loads, and then only implement one zoom on dbl click. Then if u double click again i want it to zoom out to the original position

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question about the limits: just set the extent for the scale with the maximum of `1`.

```
.scaleExtent([1, 10])
```

Here is the demo:

```js
d3.xml("https://boxy-svg.com/images/logos/boxy-svg.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", function () {
       svg.selectAll("*").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
   }))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a million.  that only allows zoom out, not zoom in. I think it should be `.scaleExtent([1, 1.5]`. Have you any idea how to toggle zoom in and zoom out on dbl click ?

Comment: no props! I think it should be something along these lines 0 http://gf.neocities.org/am/aumap.html -  as i am actually zooming in on a map svg image. So on dbl click i am trying to make it zoom on that section, and when you double click again zoom back out to the original starting position

Comment: @phantom how did you get that link of Australia map? You can check the code, I didn't use any d3 zoom.

Comment: i found it on your website :-). I got it all working yesterday